# Flutter google sign in automatically changes parse emailVerified to false, and re-sends verification e-mail

Tags: flutter, parse-platform, parse-server

I have implemented google login in my application using the '[google-sign-in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in)' plugin. Generally, when registering using this method, a user is created in the parser and the **emailVerified** field is set to **false**. Then I get an e-mail with a confirmation link, after clicking the **emailVerified** field changes to **true** - that is, as it should be. The problem is that after logging out and back in to this account, the **emailVerified** field changes back to **false** and the confirmation e-mail is sent again.

Here's my Parse Server Values:

```
    var api = new ParseServer({
    appName:config.app,
    databaseURI: config.parseServer.databaseURI, // Connection string for your MongoDB database
    collectionPrefix:config.useCollectionPrefix?config.parseServer.appId:undefined,
    cloud: config.parseServer.cloud, // Absolute path to your Cloud Code
    appId: config.parseServer.appId,
    masterKey: config.parseServer.masterKey, // Keep this key secret!
    restAPIKey: config.parseServer.restAPIKey,
    clientKey: config.parseServer.clientKey,
    javascriptKey: config.parseServer.javascriptKey,
    serverURL: config.serverURL+":"+config.parseServer.port+"/", // Don't forget to change to https if needed
    publicServerURL: config.publicServerURL+"/",
    logsFolder:'./logs/'+config.app+"/",
    verbose: false,
    verifyUserEmails: true,
    emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 2*60*60, //2h 
    filesAdapter: new FSFilesAdapter({
        "filesSubDirectory": config.app // optional
      }),
    liveQuery: {
        classNames: ["Test"] //List of classes to support for query subscritions
    },
    auth: {
        google: {}
    },
    push: {
        android: {
            senderId: 'xxxxx', // The Sender ID of GCM
            apiKey: 'xxxxxx' // The Server API Key of GCM
        }
        // ios: {
        //     pdx: 'certs/mycert.p12', // the path and filename to the .p12 file you exported earlier. 
        //     bundleId: '', // The bundle identifier associated with your app
        //     production: true
        // }
    },
   emailAdapter: SimpleSendGridAdapter({
    apiKey: 'xxxxx',
    fromAddress: 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
  }),
   // customPages: {
   //    invalidLink: 'http://yourpage/link_invalid.html',
   //    verifyEmailSuccess: 'http://yourpage/verify_email_success.html',
   //    choosePassword: 'http://yourpage/new_password.html',
   //    passwordResetSuccess: 'http://yourpage/sucess.html'
   //  },
});
```

Flutter sign in with google function code:

```
  static Future<bool> signWithGoogle() async {
    // return false;
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn( scopes: ['email'] );

    GoogleSignInAccount? account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    googleSignInAccount = account;
    if (account == null) return false;
    GoogleSignInAuthentication authentication = await account.authentication;

    ParseResponse response = await ParseUser.loginWith(
        'google',
        google(
            authentication.accessToken!,
            _googleSignIn.currentUser!.id,
            authentication.idToken!
        ),
      username: _googleSignIn.currentUser!.displayName,
      email: _googleSignIn.currentUser!.email,
    );

    if (response.success){
      return _setDeviceId(response.result);
    }else
      _handleError(response);

    return false;
  }

  static Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> googleForDataOnly() async {
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn( scopes: ['email'] );

    return await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  }
```

I'm not really sure if I have to make changes in parse server config or in flutter code.

Comment: When you login again, a new user is created or the existing user has its flag reverted to false? Have you notice if the e-mail has changed?

Comment: Existing user has its flag reverted to false. The e-mail is the same.

Comment: Would you mind to try to remove `username: _googleSignIn.currentUser!.displayName` and `email: _googleSignIn.currentUser!.email`? I believe it is related, because I know that Parse Server reverts the flag every time you touch the email field (even if setting up the same e-mail again).

Comment: Finally it works perfectly, but you have to add condition, when u log in for the first time (registering) it has to contain those two lines, then when u log in next time and you don't have those two lines it works. Thanks for help.